# How to create a PUT request in ION library

Tags: android, rest, android-ion

I am using Ion library and i should say that is awesome.
but i cannot find a documentation for creating PUT , DELETE , GET request?
if it can handle this REST Request can you guide me ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the .load(METHOD, URL) call to specify an HTTP verb.

Comment: Thank you dear koush. Your library is awesome and make my programming life so much easier

Answer (score 2):

PUT Request

```
void PutRequest(String URL)
{
    Ion.with(mContext)
            .load("PUT",URL)
            .setBodyParameter("name","foo")
            .asString();

}
```

it may help you. Check this url also https://github.com/koush/ion

Comment: @JPn you can use `DELETE` as method in the above sample in place  of `PUT`.